# How to use sweetalert in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, sweetalert, cakephp-4.x

I'm using cakphp4. I have a question about cakephp and sweet alert. Could we able to replace standard flash message with sweetalert? (i mean instead of the standard Flash Message, give Sweet Alert?)

UsersController.php

```
public function delete($slug)
 {
     $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
     $user = $this->Users->findBySlug($slug)->firstorFail();
    if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
        $this->Flash->success("Deleted Successfully");
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error('Unable to Delete user');
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
 }
```

template/element/flash/success.php

```
<?php
 if (!isset($params['escape']) || $params['escape'] !== false) {
 $message = h($message);
 }
?>
<div class="message success" onclick="this.classList.add('hidden')"> 
<?= $message ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check documentation for the [Flash component](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/flash.html). The bit you want to change is the templates you'll find at `templates/element/flash`:

```
// Uses templates/element/flash/success.php
$this->Flash->success('This was successful');

// Uses templates/element/flash/great_success.php
$this->Flash->greatSuccess('This was greatly successful');
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this lineitem

```
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
```

in the default layout, which displays every flash message (based on the templates mentioned int he answer above).

Instead of echoing it you can take the result and use it as input for sweetalert.

```
<?php $inputForSweetAlert = $this->Flash->render(); ?>
```

Answer is untested.